# Error when enable GAE option "enable_stackdriver_integration" with Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, stackdriver

When I use the option "enable_stackdriver_integration: true" on Google App Engine (Flexible PHP) with the Laravel framework to send logs (and error logs) to Google Stackdriver, it works.

But when I'm tryin to run a PHP command line (Eg: php artisan migrate) from the php docker container into an instance of the app engine, I got the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  sem_get(): failed for key 0x41019ecd: Permission denied in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 71
PHP Warning:  sem_acquire() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 81
PHP Warning:  shm_attach(): failed for key 0x41019ecd: Permission denied in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 130
PHP Warning:  shm_attach(): failed for key 0x41019ecd: Permission denied in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 156
PHP Warning:  shm_remove_var() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 157
PHP Warning:  sem_release() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 91
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to attach to the shared memory in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php:132
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/BatchRunner.php(191): Google\Cloud\Core\Batch\SysvConfigStorage->load()
#1 /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/BatchRunner.php(74): Google\Cloud\Core\Batch\BatchRunner->loadConfig()
#2 /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/BatchTrait.php(201): Google\Cloud\Core\Batch\BatchRunner->__construct()
#3 /app/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/PsrLogger.php(150): Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger->setCommonBatchProperties(Array)
#4 /app/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/LoggingClient.php(575): Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger->__construct(Object(Google\Cloud\Logging\Logger), NULL, Array)
#5 /app/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/Bootstrap.php(40): Google\Cloud\Logging\LoggingClient->psrLogger('app-error', Array)
#6 /app/vendor/google/cloud-error-reporting/src/prepend.php(68): Google\Cloud\ErrorReporting\Bootstrap::init(NULL)
#7  in /app/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/Batch/SysvConfigStorage.php on line 132
```

Off course, if I remove the option from the app.yaml there is no problem. Do you know why ?

Comment: This seems like a product issue, and there was already an issue opened on [Google's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110950254) where the person who opened it asked to close it right away. I reopened it now and you can follow its progress from the link.

Comment: Hi @pessolato can give your views on stackdriver using in cakephp

Comment: I have the same issue but only when I run a ./bin/console